# What is expected installation time of Visual Studio 2010 professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I have got i5-560m dell laptop with windows 7 (x64) on board with 8gb 1333 ddr ram. I started installation of VS 2010 professional with full option.... something like 12 hours ago... and it is still at 4th component on installation list. It does something because after hour... progress bar is moving.... but that crappy installation window has got problems with refreshing itself so I cannot toggle it to visibility by alt+tab or click on it.... just minimizing everything brings it to my eyes. But this is not main issue. The most confusing aspect is the process itself! It consumes already 3,9 GB of RAM with CPU load of 22%... and acts very slowly when whole system responds very quickly even though over 5gb of RAM is consumed now.

My question is... there is any magic I should do before I run this installer (which is marked as 32-bit process in task manager - why?). Sincerely I killed almost all redundant processes after 8 hours because thought some other stuff blocks it... but didn't help at all. How long it should take? Could it be somehow speed ed up?

Comment: It should not take that long. What are you installing it from DVD, file, ISO?

Comment: Perhaps this is more suited to SuperUser based on the software orientated aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't take that long. I would say maybe half an hour max. The setup is probably hung up waiting for some resource or input from another process (I've had setup's hang for several minutes because of UAC before).

I would say do this:

- Cancel the install
- Turn off UAC
- Reboot your system
- Try the install again. **Note:** If it's from a DVD, try making an image of it and installing from there via Daemon Tools or Alcohol 120%.
- Don't forget to turn UAC back on.

If you have UAC turned off, try turning it on, maybe VS is looking for that.

Comment: It is from web installer (it has been downloaded everything). after 12 hours... I was prompted with dialog: A problem with Asp.NET MVC2 component has been encountered..... and whole installation has been stopped. Dear God please .... protect me from M$ crappy stuff. I have no words... I am totally devastated....

Comment: @Piotr Mąsior - Wow. That sounds terrible. Try getting the full installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/try). It's 2.28GB but worth it in my opinion. I dislike web installers, personally.

Comment: @Drackir: I killed this stupid process and started web installer once again... he skipped downloading (maybe somewhere cached) and start install once again - much faster in my experience now... but components queue is different. I will see if it will "repaired". I am asked by installer for restart now... so it if really freaky!

Comment: @Piotr Mąsior - Good luck! (Also, just so you know, you don't have to use the @Name if it's in my own answer. I will get notified either way. :) )

Comment: Installer has got now 25 mb RAM usage and progress bar goes like a rocket. I have no idea why there was so heavy load before. Now I can see that something really is happening with installer actions. There should be some bold warning on Microsoft download page: "If installation takes more than hour - restart installer looser !" Thanks for responses. Regards!

Comment: @Piotr Mąsior - The only thing I've ever seen that successfully installed after more than half an hour (not including Windows installs :-P ) was the Adobe Suite . They're installers are the worst ever. Anyways, I'm glad it's working now. :-)

Comment: why should it take longer to install this virtual studio than to install any operating system? I am at best puzzled...

Comment: @RickyRobinson Well for one thing, if I recall correctly, the VS install is actually larger than the OS. I think it's 10GB+. Also, it installs many sub-programs and patches, each of which has to initiate its own install process.

Answer (score -1):

I install it in 10-20 mins. Something is wrong with your laptop. If you got antivirus app disable it, if the matter still exist, then probably that's cause of viruses or spywares. Another possibility is misconfiguration of windows or some apps.

The best solution is reinstalling windows.

Comment: Reinstalling windows is a bit of overkill if you ask me. What do you do if the windows reinstall fails? :-P